# Yii findByAttribute() function WITH() relations query

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have this `findByAttributes()` funtion with a relation to the `userRemoteIdentities` model

```
$record = User::model()->with('userRemoteIdentities')->findByAttributes(
                        array('email' => $remoteProfile->email),
                        array(
                            'condition' =>'provider = :provider AND identifier = :identifier',
                            'params'=>array(':provider'=> strtolower($_GET['provider']), ':identifier'=> $remoteProfile->identifier)
                        )
                    );
```

problem is it queries both tables with an `AND`

```
 WHERE (`t`.`email`=:yp0 AND (provider = :provider AND identifier = :identifier)
```

how would i get it to use an `OR` like this?

```
WHERE (`t`.`email`=:yp0 OR (provider = :provider AND identifier = :identifier))
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use second and third params in addColumnCondition

Create function in model

```
 public function yourFunctionName($provider, $remoteProfile){
          $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
          $criteria->with = 'userRemoteIdentities';
          $criteria->addColumnCondition(['email' => $remoteProfile->email]);
          $criteria->addColumnCondition(['provider' => strtolower($provider), 'identifier' => $remoteProfile->identifier], 'AND', 'OR');
          return $this->findAll($criteria);
   }
```

Call

```
$record = User::model()->yourFunctionName($_GET['provider'], $remoteProfile);
```

P.S. I used short array syntax.